# How do you detemine floating point nearest to 0.0 or 1.0 In Java

Tags: java, math

Given two float pointing numbers between 0.0 and 1.0, I want to determine which one is nearest to 0 or 1. The numbers are stored as BigDecimal if that is easier to deal with than converting to Floats.

e.g

- a=0.8, b=0.4 return a
- a=0.6, b=0.1 return b

Comment: Are you asking for code, pseudo code, or a built in function?

Comment: What about `a=0.8` and `b=0.2`?

Comment: Nearest to zero or one?  Which one is it?  In your first case a is nearest to one; b is nearest to zero.  Which one does your requirement say you should return?

Comment: Nearest to zero or one - I mean either if b is nearer to zero or 1 then a is , then return b otherwise return a. In the case of a=08, b=02 it doesnt really matter they are both equally close.

Comment: I was looking for some Jave code that hopefully could make of existing function, I assume what Im doing is mathematically common, I dont knw the right terminlogy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the distance from 0.5 subtract 0.5 from each, get the absolute value, and return the larger

Answer (score 0):

Coded the solution given by ControlAltDel

```
private static boolean isAFurthestFromHalf(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b)
    {
        BigDecimal HALF = new BigDecimal(0.5);
        if (a.subtract(HALF).abs().compareTo(b.subtract(HALF).abs())>=0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```